# ORION: Getting the list of subscriptions

Tags: fiware-orion

I am interested in accessing the list of active subscriptions, but after reading all the wiki about APIs (https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Context_subscriptions) i haven't find any operation that allows to get the list of them.

Is there any operation to do that? Anyone can give me details about it?

Answer (score 5):

The NGSI API that Orion implements doesn't include any operation to get the list of existing subscription. It is assumed that each client knows the subscription it has created and manages it, no "administrative action" to get them all has been defined by NGSI.

The only posibility with the current Orion version is to query directly the database to get that information (e.g. in a side REST server running along the Orion context broker process). Considering the data model described in [the Orion documentation](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Collections), it is a matter of queriying on the csubs collection.

**EDIT:** Orion 0.25.0 includes an operation to get a list of subscriptions in the NGISv2 API: `GET /v2/subscriptions`. See [this document](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) for details.

Comment: The operation to get a list of existing subscriptions is on roadmap (see `GET /v1/contextSubscriptions` at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj_S9VF3rt5DdEhqZHlBaGVURmhZRDY3aDRBdlpHS3c#gid=0)