# Orion Context Broker: List of alive subscriptions via REST API?

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there any way to retrieve a list of the current or alive subscriptions with their subscriptionID through the REST API of the ContextBroker? I do not see it inside the list of available operations in the documentation.

If it is not possible what is the recommendation if you want to delete subscriptions that you do not need anymore besides waiting for the duration to expire. Directly accessing mongoDB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question (list of existing subsctiptions) has been answered in the following post: [ORION: Getting the list of subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990910/orion-getting-the-list-of-subscriptions)

Regarding the second part of the question (how to delete subscription you don't need anymore) if the subscription is already expired you can apply the procedure described in the [Deleting expired documents section at administration manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Deleting_expired_documents). If the subscription is not expired, you have to find its ID querying directly to MongoDB (`_id` field in the csubs collection), then deleting it (either at MongoDB or using the [unsubscribeContext operation](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#ONTIMEINTERVAL) in the REST API).