# How to list all subscriptions via API on Orion Context Broker?

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm having issues with entities which has subscriptions and wanted to list all of them to check which one is problematic. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORION: Getting the list of subscriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990910/orion-getting-the-list-of-subscriptions)

Comment: @fgalan is right, there is a very similar question on link that contains the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thus, I understand this question should be marked as duplicated, but I don't know how to do it...